# Automate Javascript Execution through Console on Different Proxies

Tags: javascript, proxy

Basically, I was able to run this javascript command on a specific web page successfully through a proxy via hide.me, and my end goal would be some way to automate the following process:

1) Load the website through a random proxy server (doesn't have to be via hide.me)

2) Use Console to execute a javascript command

3) Repeat 1 and 2 using a different proxy server

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use headless browser [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. You can use their example for loading websites:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  phantom.exit();
});
```

You can specify proxy in [command line arguments](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

You can do the javascript calls by using `page.evaluate`:

```
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
      // or other js calls
      return document.getElementById('myagent').textContent;
    });
    console.log(ua);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

PhantomJS can hang on `var page = require('webpage').create();` until `phantom.exit()` will be called. Try to log your `page.open(status)` status and maybe website is faulty.

Comment: This looks excellent! How would I do the javascript calls? Also, phantomjs seems to hang at: var page = require('webpage').create();

Comment: Never mind, I'm dumb, I totally didn't see the ); at the end. It works, just need to figure out how to make the javascript function calls. They are functions that are specific to the webpage I'm accessing, but in the Console in Chrome, I'm able to just write them out just as they're called in the page's source code, and when I hit Enter, it works fine. EDIT: Just saw your edits, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Run it in `page.evaluate`, example is in my answer: `document.getElementById('myagent').textContent;`. Have you tried that?

Comment: It SEEMS to have worked, but I'm not entirely sure. The javascript function calls don't return anything as far as I know, but when I call them via Chrome, a popup is displayed on the webpage. I used page.evaluate() with the function calls inside, and they seem to be executed, but after I call page.evaluate(), I do page.render() and save the page as a jpg, but when I open the png, the popups aren't there. I'm thus not entirely sure they're actually being called

Comment: After you call your function try to find `popup` element in DOM if it is present and visible. I wouldn't rely on images. If popup won't be displayed after call, try checking at later time using `setTimeout`, so you give it time to run page logic.

Comment: Never mind, I stand corrected. I realized that sometimes, when I rendered, the loading icon would show up (the website is somewhat resource-heavy). I simply added some setTimeOut stuff and it worked fine, popup and all! thanks so much for your help! now i'll just get a list of proxy servers and batch run this. Awesome!

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote. Thanks so much man! Batch script is running! :D